# Tag list Drop Down Menu

Tags: wordpress

I am wondering how to create a simple tag drop-down menu (all tags included DESC) without rewriting the WP core functions. It has to work outside of any loop.

**wp_tag_cloud()** with the 'format=array' attribute would seem the best choice since it works outside of any loop/template and returns all available tags sorted A-Z (which I need) but the array values contain HTML formatting (instead of just a plain string value) and that is not suitable for creating the drop-down.

i.e.:

```
<?php $tag = wp_tag_cloud('format=array');  // 'format=array' contains <a>link</> !!!

foreach($tag as $tagkey => $tagvalue)       // ...need to be somehow filtered out !!
{
echo "<option value='".$tagvalue."'>".$tagvalue."</option>";
}
?>
```

The **get_the_tag_list()** function works great but it doesn't work outside of the template (loop).

Is there a simple way how to get the list of all tags so I can put them into the drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

...OMG! I can't believe I actually asked this publicly!

Of course the code is ...

```
<?php $tag = wp_tag_cloud('format=array' );

foreach($tag as $tagkey => $tagvalue)
{
$cleanedup = strip_tags($tagvalue);
echo "<option value='".$cleanedup."'>".$cleanedup."</option>";
}

?>
```